# Can a connection be shared in DBCP when evictor thread is used?

Tags: java

My dbcp configuration is as follows. (dbcp-1.3)

```
    <property name="initialSize" value="36" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="36" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="36" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="-1"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="40"/>
```

And I want to know that there is a chance when a connection borrowed from a pool can be shared by validation query execute.

For example

```
        while (true) {
            connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection(); // get connection from DBCP
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM t1");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            ....
            ....
            ....
            // DBCP validation query invoked by evictor thread at this point.
            // can this connection object can be executed simultaneously by dbcp evictor thread?
            ....
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please explain in more detail what you want to do and try to clarify your question.

Comment: I just want to know if a connection can be shared between threads when timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis property is enabled.

Comment: Why do you think sharing a connection between threads (which btw is (almost) always a bad idea) would behave differently then when it is used by a single thread? I still don't really understand your problem and question, though.